# Find value from range inside a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

If there is a way to create formula which try to find any value from range in a cell and returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` -- depending on the result?

For example let `A1` cell contain `"Some word to find in a longer text."`, column `B` 4 cells: `word`, `longer`, `shorter`, `closer` and if we apply the formula in `C1` then we got `TRUE` because at least one of the values from column `B` was found in `A1` (`word` and `longer`).
But if in `C2` we examine `A2` which contains `"Some text which doesn’t contain any."` then we got `FALSE`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using one of the following formulas:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C1</kbd>

```
=SUM(N(TEXTSPLIT(A1,{" ","."})=$B$1:$B$4))>0
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=SUM(1-ISERR(SEARCH($B$1:$B$4,A1)))>0
```

---

Here is a screenshot below, explains clearly on what the second formula does:

[image]

---

- Using `SEARCH()` function it searches the words in range `Column B` present in Cell `A1` --> `=SEARCH($B$1:$B$4,A1)`
- Using `ISERR()` instead of `ISNUMBER()` which will not work the same way until `1` is subtracted from the array, so using `ISNUMBER()` we get `TRUE` for the matches `FALSE` for non, while `ISERR()` does the reverse and hence why `1` is subtracted. --> <sup>**1**</sup> `=ISERR(D1#)` --> <sup>**2**</sup> `=1-E1#`
- Lastly, using `SUM()` to sum all the values in the array and to check whether its greater than `0` or not, if yes then it returns `TRUE` else `FALSE`. --> `=SUM(F1#)>0`

---

Also if one tries to evaluate the formula then they would understand or get a clear clarification on which each of the function does.

---

Comment: Well... thank you, it helps somehow but the second formula seems like searching only for the value from same row, not the whole range. The first though I cannot use in Libreoffice since it hasn't got `TEXTSPLIT` function :(

Comment: @friedman both the formulas are using the whole range i.e. `$B$1:$B$4` to search a value in a string places in cell `A1`

Comment: Well, not really. Please check: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JpBErPmo2uOxgkJabdX9_Y6R1ij-PHXHGuZOvbNcTLU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What you have posted and what you are showing is hell and heaven difference. Doesn't really make sense at all. Also if you are question is related with `Google-Sheets` then i cant say anything

Comment: What? It's the same thing. How is it different? I've only pasted it to Google Sheet to make it available online.

Comment: There is no such function in Excel called `=arrayformula(SUM(1-ISERR(SEARCH($B$1:$B$4;A1)))>0)` --> `ARRAYFORMULA()`. also i see the formula still works

Comment: What? It's the sheet with formula you have suggested in column C.

Comment: If your formula was right it should show TRUE in C1, TRUE in C2, TRUE in C3 and FALSE in C4

Comment: And how is it not working, as per the screenshot it is working, in google sheets you have to add the arrayformula to make it work, while in excel if using lower version of excel then needs to hit Ctrl shift enter but in MS365 it doesnt require. the column D shows its working **[See Here](https://imgur.com/gallery/BWjtTTE)**

Comment: It is working, you should try in Excel instead of Google Sheets, both are different applications, since its an array formula it needs to hit CTRL SHIFT ENTER while exiting the edit mode for versions lower than MS365 or Excel 2021. I am using MS365 so i dont requrie.

Comment: OK, maybe it's the case of moving between Excel, Libreoffice and Google Sheets. Actualy Libreoffice should be the main target and maybe that's the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I will try to explain again. The formula shown using `ISERR()` and `SEARCH()` is a dynamic array formula, which if used in versions of Excel like `MS365` or `Excel 2021` dont require to hit `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` while exiting the edit mode, but if using versions from `Excel 2019` to `Excel 2010` will require to hit `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`. Also for `Google Sheets` to make it work one needs to wrap within `ARRAYFORMULA()` . All applications are different and their functionalities differs a lot.